# Controling number of records returning from database in DataTables jQuery

Tags: jquery, datatable

If anybody can please help me with this question: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/23256/controling-number-of-records-returning-from-database-but-save-number-of-pages-and-total-number#latest
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use LIMIT 0,1000 for first 1000 record and you can access with page number and count with following function.

```
 function get_limit_query($page,$page_count) {
    $limit="";
    if($page_count>0 && ($page=="" || $page==false)) {
        $page=1;
    }
    if($page==false)
        $limit="";
    else {
        if(intval($page_count)<=0)
            $page_count=10;
        $initial=(($page-1)*$page_count);
        if($initial<0)
            $initial=0;
        $limit=" LIMIT ".$initial.", ".$page_count;
    }
    return $limit;
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ".get_limit_query(1,1000));
```